# Prolate spheroidal coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry, multivariable-calculus

If $\alpha \in (0,\infty)$, $\beta \in (0,\pi)$ and $\theta \in (0,2\pi)$. 
$$\varphi (\alpha,\beta,\theta) =(
\sinh(\alpha)\sin(\beta)\cos(\theta),
\sinh(\alpha)\sin(\beta)\sin(\theta),
\cosh(\alpha)\cos(\beta))
$$

How to prove is that a diffeomorphism? I proved that fixed $\alpha_0$ then 
$$\varphi_{\alpha_0} = (
\sinh(\alpha_0)\sin(\beta)\cos(\theta),
\sinh(\alpha_0)\sin(\beta)\sin(\theta),
\cosh(\alpha_0)\cos(\beta))$$

is a parametrization.

Comment: To prove a mapping is a diffeomorphism, you might need the definition of a diffeomorphism.  Do you know what that is?

Comment: Bijection differentiable with its inverse differentiable. In this case $$\varphi: (0,\infty)\times (0,\pi)\times (0,2\pi) \to \mathbb{R}^3 \backslash \text{plane xz}$$. I was tried to prove using the fact that a composition of diffeomorphism is a diffeomorphism.